# Case Queue in API as attribute on Case?

Tags: rest-api, api, soap-api, case, python

[image: Case Queue]

I was wondering if it is possible to retrieve the value that the case is assigned to by using the api similar to how I retrieve other values associated with the case. I am currently using the soapbox library for python. Or is there logic that the front end of sf does to just look at the CaseHistory? Would be great if it was just an attribute of case. Any Tips?

Answer (score 1):

In many ways, a Queue is no different than a User. A case assigned to a Queue will be "owned" by the Queue. The OwnerId is a polymorphic key. You'd need to query using `TypeOf` with the `OwnerId` to reach the Queue.

In Salesforce terms, a Queue is actually a Group with a Type specified as 'Queue'. It will have a `QueueId` and it's members are Users. In a query using TypeOf being 'Group', you should be able to query the Queue to get more info on it since you'd have it's Id from the `OwnerId` of the Case if assigned to the Queue. See the [ObjectReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/) on Group and QueueSObject for more info. Also see the Working with [Polymorphic Relationships in SOQL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_polymorphic_relationships.htm) in the Apex Developer Guide.